# Is there an easy way to to collect a large number variables into a list or list of lists?

Tags: list-manipulation, variable

I have a large number of variables in a notebook from a data analysis routine, the results of which now need to be fed through a mathematical model and various items for visualization.

For example, I have several dozen variables with names like "EV15147", "EV15147aDIP", "EV15147aMCP", "EV15147aPIP", "EV15196", 
"EV15196aDIP", "EV15196aMCP". I would like to be able to collect specific variables into a list that I can easily call. As an example, a list made up of all the variables with names that start with "EV15" and end with "aMCP". Is there a way/routine to collect variables using wildcards?

I am aware I could have prevented this by starting with a variable that was a list of lists to begin with, but hindsight is 20/20 and rewriting the code to do this would be just as time-consuming as individually running the values through the model and visualizations.

I have looked around for and didn't see anything that could solve my issue, if I did please point me in the right direction.

Comment: ``Names["EV15*aMCP"]`` will give the list as strings.  Then you could just use `ToExpression` or some form of `Hold`

Comment: Keeping the global flag in there was making the wildcards unhappy. Thanks for your suggestion! It did the trick.